# How can one catch a Web api returning other than 200 OK, with a WCF client?

Tags: wcf

I am calling a Web Api with a tool using a wcf client. I have to use that tool, so I cannot use WebRequest or WebClient or any other code. I can neither infer a try/catch on the method call.

What I can do is to configure the WCF client, so if I can catch/inspect the status code elsewhere (custom behavior/binding/channel) it would be fine.

I already have a behavior that calls a method (with a webrequest) and get a token. This token is used for the actual method I want to call. This token can be invalidated at any time and then the method will return 401 Unauthorized and I need to get a new token and make the call again. Unfortunately the AfterReply method in my behavior is not getting hit, the error is cached on a "lower" level.

If I Google this questions many answers occurs, but I have not found any other answers than using another clent. There must be somewhere in the WCF stack/pipeline one can hook in.

Any suggestions or other approaches?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *WebOperationContext* after you received the reply to check the status code:

```
WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingResponse.StatusCode
```

Comment: Thank for reply. The problem I have is that I must hook into WCF stack somewhere to get the reply. In the behavior I am using I have BeforeRequest an AfterReply,  and the exception occurs between those and is propagated up to the client''s method call, pasing my code. I need to intercept that. I have tried ApplyClientErrorHandler,  but it does only work for SOAP, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For some server error that not executed on server side (500,401), it is impossible that we could captured it on client side with Fault exception.
[How can I get WCF FaultException when server returns an HTTP 401?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044469/how-can-i-get-wcf-faultexception-when-server-returns-an-http-401)
Instead, for some communication errors, ArgumentException, InvalidOperationException. It could be captured by the client side with fault exception.
You could refer to the following example about how to use IErrorHandler interface.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:1100");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri))
            {
                ServiceEndpoint se = sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                    smb.HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:1100/mex");
                    sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                }
                MyEndpointBehavior bhv = new MyEndpointBehavior();
                se.EndpointBehaviors.Add(bhv);


                sh.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("service is ready");
                Console.ReadKey();
                sh.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    [ServiceContract(ConfigurationName = "isv")]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Delete(int value);
        [OperationContract]
        void UpdateAll();
    }
    [ServiceBehavior(ConfigurationName = "sv")]
    public class MyService : IService
    {
        public string Delete(int value)
        {
            if (value <= 0)
            {
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                throw new ArgumentException("Parameter should be greater than 0");
            }
            return "Hello";
        }

        public void UpdateAll()
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Operation exception");
        }
    }
    public class MyCustomErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
    {
        public bool HandleError(Exception error)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
        {
            FaultException faultException = new FaultException(error.Message);
            MessageFault messageFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();
            fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, messageFault, error.Message);

        }
}
    public class MyEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            MyCustomErrorHandler myCustomErrorHandler = new MyCustomErrorHandler();
            endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(myCustomErrorHandler);
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            return;
        }
}
```

**Client.**

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
            try
            {
                client.Delete(-1);
            }
            catch (FaultException fault)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fault.Reason.GetMatchingTranslation().Text);
            }
        }
}
```

**App.config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:1100/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
        </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I have no control over the service, and not even the client, only the client behavior. I have had some success using an message interceptor, not inspector, but have not landed it yet.

Comment: For the part that 500 and 401 not reaching server/service code, I am not so sure. I wrote a mock service that only returned http status 401, and that code was reached. If the authorization is in the Web server, then it will not hit service code, but that is not my case, it is the REST service returning 401, not the web server. But in my case that does not matter, I only need to handle it anyhow.